# Obtain a submatrix of a NumPy ndarray using a generator expression

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I want to obtain a submatrix of a NumPy `ndarray` using [`numpy.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) and a sequence of indexes from a generator expression. In the following toy example, why does this not work:

```
import numpy as np

m = np.arange(25).reshape((5, 5))
ind = (i for i in range(0, 6, 2))
m[np.ix_(ind, ind)]
```

throwing a `ValueError: Cross index must be 1 dimensional`, whereas, using a list comprehension:

```
ind = [i for i in range(0, 6, 2)]
m[np.ix_(ind, ind)]
```

produces the expected result:

```
array([[ 0,  2,  4],
       [10, 12, 14],
       [20, 22, 24]])
```

Comment: Because `np.ix_` doesn't accepts a generator. You can simply use `np.arange()` to produce your indices.

Comment: I see. I can't use `np.arange` because my indices require a comprehension syntax, so I'll just have to use a list comprehension

Comment: just slice? `m[:6:2, :6:2]`

Comment: I used a toy example to illustrate the problem I was having with generators. In my real case, I need more complicated indexing of the array, so I can't slice as you suggest. I'll settle on using a list comp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus just on the `ix_` step; here's the full error message:

```
In [255]: ind = (i for i in range(0, 6, 2))
In [256]: np.ix_(ind, ind)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-256-920b314f7f36> in <module>()
----> 1 np.ix_(ind, ind)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py in ix_(*args)
     75         new = asarray(new)
     76         if new.ndim != 1:
---> 77             raise ValueError("Cross index must be 1 dimensional")
     78         if new.size == 0:
     79             # Explicitly type empty arrays to avoid float default

ValueError: Cross index must be 1 dimensional
```

It's turning each input object into an array.  That works fine with the input is already an array, or is a list. But with a generator expression:

```
In [257]: np.asarray(ind)
Out[257]: array(<generator object <genexpr> at 0xae9e28fc>, dtype=object)
```

we get a 0d object array.  It does not expand the generator into a list.  That's your job.

```
In [258]: np.ix_(list(ind), list(ind))
Out[258]: 
(array([[0],
        [2],
        [4]]), array([], shape=(1, 0), dtype=int32))
```

Oops - the 2nd index is empty, shape (1,0)!  Any guesses as to why?

The primary purpose of `ix_` is add the appropriate dimensions to the inputs so they broadcast right.

```
In [259]: np.ix_([0,2,4],[1,2,3])
Out[259]: 
(array([[0],
        [2],
        [4]]), array([[1, 2, 3]]))
```

Indexing with that will be quite different from indexing with

```
x[[0,2,4], [1,2,3]]
```

One returns a (3,3) array, the other a (3,) array.

Generators don't get used much with arrays.  We normally work with the WHOLE array.  Generators are for lazy evaluation of list, or rather several layers of lists.